# Unable to bind scope variable of modal from directive angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am having trouble binding the scope variable of a modal in a directive used by the modal. I have tried all the solutions on the net. I have tried the `$parent` solution too, but nothing seems to work. I am new to Angularjs, so please help me out. Below is the code :

directive:

```
.directive('searchPart', function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AEC',
            transclude:true,
            scope: {
                items: '=',
                prompt:'@',
                title: '@',
                subtitle:'@',
                model: '=',
                onSelect:'&'
            },
            link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
                scope.handleSelection=function(selectedItem){
                    scope.model=selectedItem;

                    scope.current=0;
                    scope.selected=true;
                    $timeout(function(){
                        scope.onSelect();
                    },200);
                };
                scope.current=0;
                scope.selected=true;
                scope.isCurrent=function(index){
                    return scope.current==index;
                };
                scope.setCurrent=function(index){
                    scope.current=index;
                };
            },
            templateUrl: 'admin/product/catalogView/partSearch.html'
        }
    })
```

modal controller:

```
.controller('ChildPartEditCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, Data, $http) {
        $scope.name="";
        $scope.onItemSelected=function(){
            console.log('selected='+$scope.name);
        }}
```

html:

```
 <search-part items="items" prompt="Enter full part number" title="name" subtitle="abbreviation" model="name" on-select="onItemSelected()" />
```

**Template**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" placeholder="{{prompt}}" ng-keydown="selected=false" />
<br/>
<div class="items" ng-hide="!model.length || selected">
    <div class="item" 
      ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{partnumber:model}  track by $index" 
      ng-click="handleSelection(item.partnumber)" style="cursor:pointer" 
      ng-class="{active:isCurrent($index)}" 
      ng-mouseenter="setCurrent($index)">
        <p class="title">{{item.partnumber}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which binding is not working..? What exactly is your issue..?

Comment: ok if you can see the template i am setting the model with the item.partnumber value. in the directive it is getting set in the scope.model . bu the same isnt reflecting in $scope.name in the search-part directive

Comment: even the nooff , part description are not getting set in the scope of the modal controller. i understand i have to use objects instead of scope. but how do i achieve that from directive too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you're assigning a primitive value to model. You should have an object in controller, for example:

```
$scope.selected = {name: ''}
```

then pass `selected` as the model:

```
<search-part items="items" prompt="Enter full part number" title="name" subtitle="abbreviation" model="selected" on-select="onItemSelected()" />
```

and set `scope.model.name=selectedItem` in the directive, that should work.

This works because objects are passed by value, with the objects reference (memory  location) as value. So `scope.model` will point to the controller scopes `selected` object. `scope.model.name=selectedItem` will update it's `name` property.

Primitives are passed by it's actual value, in your original code, `scope.model` doesn't point to controllers scope at all.

Comment: Thanx a ton! Worked like a charm